# Style not inherited after ul li tag to a span text

Tags: html-lists, html, inheritance

Consider the following html code. The parent paragraph style should be inherited to   and to the last  text. However, the paragraph style is not inherited to last  text. The  tag is causing some issue. Without  tag, the last  text would be styled as defined in the paragraph class.

```
<body>
<p class="paragraph_class1">
    <span>Start paragraph.</span>
    <ul class="list_class3">
        <li class="paragraph_class1 list_detail_class4">
            <span class="text_class5">List item</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span>End paragraph.</span>
</p></body>

    .paragraph_class1
{
color: #ff0000;
border-top-color: #0000ff;
border-left-color: #0000ff;
border-right-color: #0000ff;
border-bottom-color: #0000ff;
border-top-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the class to the span tag like so:

`<span class="paragraph_class1">End paragraph.</span>`

And remember to enclose your css in  style-tags

Usually you shouldn't nest ul-tags in p-tags

Comment: I tried adding the class from paragraph tag to span tag. It ended up having multiple border to the text "End paragraph".

Not having ul-tag within p-tag might be not possible at the current time as the html and css is being being written dynamically (through java code based of design).

Is there any other alternative to fix this to inherit the properties from p tag?